# Confusion with lottery probabilities.

Tags: combinatorics

#### Problem

I tried to compute some probabilities for a lottery (6/49 to be specific) and found a discrepancy between two ways to compute the same probability, so I must have done something wrong. But I do not see at which point my thoughts diverge from reality.

The lottery works as follows. There are $N$($=49$) numbers to choose from ($1,\dots,N$) and a correct solution consisting of $n$($=6$) of those numbers all different from one another. The player tries to guess the correct solution by also choosing $n$ distinct numbers. The order of the numbers does not matter.

Mathematically, the solution space $\mathcal L$ consists of all subsets of $\{1,\dots,N\}$ with cardinality $n$, and has $|\mathcal L|=\binom Nn$ elements. If $\ell_0\in\mathcal L$ is the correct solution, then $C(\ell)=|\ell\cap\ell_0|$ is the number of correctly guessed numbers.

I tried to find formulas for $P(C=k)$ and $P(C\geq k)$, but the formulas I found do not satisfy $P(C\geq k)=\sum_{j=k,\dots,n}P(C=j)$ even though $\{C\geq k\}=\bigcup_{j=k,\dots,n}\{C=j\}$ is a disjoint union.

#### My approach

To find $P(C=k)=|\{C=k\}|\big/|\mathcal L|$ I need to count all sets $\ell\in\mathcal L$ where $k$ numbers are correct (i.e. belong to $\ell_0$) and where the other $n-k$ numbers of $\ell$ are not correct (i.e. belong to $\{1,\dots,N\}\setminus\ell_0$). I count $\binom nk$ possibilities for the former condition and $\binom{N-n}{n-k}$ possibilities for the latter condition, giving me $$P(C=k)=\frac{\displaystyle\binom nk\binom{N-n}{n-k}}{\displaystyle\binom Nn}.$$

Similarly, to find $P(C\geq k)=|\{C\geq k\}|\big/|\mathcal L|$ I need to count all sets $\ell\in\mathcal L$ where $k$ numbers are correct (i.e. belong to $\ell_0$) and where the other $n-k$ numbers of $\ell$ are arbitrary (i.e. can be any of the remaining $N-k$ numbers, regardless of whether they are correct or not). I count $\binom nk$ possibilities for the former condition and $\binom{N-k}{n-k}$ possibilities for the latter condition, giving me $$P(C\geq k)=\frac{\displaystyle\binom nk\binom{N-k}{n-k}}{\displaystyle\binom Nn}$$

#### Error

If I compute $P(C\geq k)$ using the formulas above for $(N,n,k)=(49,6,3)$ I get

$$
P(C\geq k)
=\frac{50}{2,303}
\color{red}\neq
\frac{4,654}{249,711}
=\frac{8,815}{499,422}+\frac{645}{665,896}+\frac{43}{2,330,636}+\frac{1}{13,983,816}
=\sum_{j=k,\dots,n}P(C=j),
$$

which means I miscounted $\{C\geq k\}$ and $\bigcup_{j=k,\dots,n}\{C=j\}$ by about 43,000 elements. I strongly suspect that my formula for $P(C\geq k)$ is wrong. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Your $P(C\ge k)$ is overcounting. For example $(N, n, k) = (49, 6, 3)$ and if the winning solution is $\ell_0 = \{1,\ldots, 6\}$, then $\ell$ like $\{1,2,3,4,48,49\}$ are counted multiple times, because the $1,...,4$ are counted both among the $k$ numbers $\in \ell_0$ and among the $n-k$ arbitrary numbers.

Comment: Maybe the summation formula is the easiest, though I have not tried simplifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solutions $\ell$ that has $j$ matching numbers, your $P(C\ge k)$ formula is overcounting $\binom jk$ times as many as it should be.

For example $(N, n, k) = (49, 6, 3)$ and if the winning solution is $\ell_0 = \{1,\ldots, 6\}$, then $\ell$ like $\{1,2,3,4,48,49\}$ are counted multiple times, because the $1,...,4$ are counted both among the $k$ numbers $\in \ell_0$ and among the $n-k$ arbitrary numbers.

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=k}^n P(C=j)&\ne\sum_{j=k}^n \binom{j}{k}P(C=j)\\
&= \sum_{j=k}^n \binom{j}{k}\cdot\frac{\dbinom nj\dbinom{N-n}{n-j}}{\dbinom Nn}\\
&= \frac{1}{\dbinom Nn}\sum_{j=k}^n\dbinom nj\dbinom jk\dbinom{N-n}{n-j}\\
&= \frac{1}{\dbinom Nn}\sum_{j=k}^n\dbinom nk\dbinom {n-k}{j-k}\dbinom{N-n}{n-j}&\dbinom nj\dbinom jk = \dbinom nk\dbinom {n-k}{j-k}\\
&= \frac{\dbinom nk}{\dbinom Nn}\sum_{j=k}^n\dbinom {n-k}{j-k}\dbinom{N-n}{n-j}\\
&= \frac{\dbinom nk}{\dbinom Nn}\sum_{j'=0}^{n-k}\dbinom {n-k}{j'}\dbinom{N-n}{n-k-j'}&j' = j-k\\
&= \frac{\dbinom nk}{\dbinom Nn}\dbinom{N-k}{n-k} &\text{by Vandermonde's identity}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! This problem has driven me crazy for the last couple of hours. P.S. Very nice proof :)